# PDO SQL Server extension faulting intermittently

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, pdo

I'm getting intermittent `Error 101 connection reset` and `Error 15 Socket Not Connected` from my dev server after switching database drivers. The reason seems to be the PDO Sqlsrv drivers I'm trying to use to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database using the SQL Server 2008 R2 SQL Native Client.

My windows event log shows this in Application Errors right at the time of each failure:
:

> Faulting application path: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\bin\httpd.exe
>   Faulting module path: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.11\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 running Apache 2.2.17 from WAMPServer 2.1, the issue occurs on both PHP version 5.2.11 and 5.3.9. The old mssql driver worked fine on 5.2.11.

I got the latest versions of the drivers from [the official Sqlsrv driver project on codeplex](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/). I'm using the Thread Safe version of the drivers as I'm using thread safe PHP. [I confirmed thread safety is not the issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/f43a9281-dadd-45e2-8147-c6613a5d6eac/)/ I used the VC6 version of the drivers with PHP 5.2.11 as my copy was compiled with VC++ 6, and I used the VC9 versions of the driver with 5.3.9 as it's compiled with VC9.

What is the problem or how can I isolate it?

Comment: driver issue huh? That's a tricky one.

Comment: I was using PHP 5.2 because my old framework version did not support it. I can now use 5.3 and would like to use the most up to date stuff, but I want whatever to *work*. The modified date on these sqlsrv drivers is 2010, is there seriously nothing more up to date?

Comment: Why the "off topic" votes? This relates directly to programming (it's my PHP set up) and doesn't seem on topic for Server Fault, it's a programmer problem not a sysadmin problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently the result of an incorrect server configuration. Reinstalling the server from scratch and using PHP 5.3.9, Apache 2.2.21 and the sqlsrv driver 2.0 worked with *fresh copies* of the php.ini and httpd.conf files. I believe I improperly copied some settings from the old server's configuration which caused wonky behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is an updated version that adds support for SQL Server 2012, though I don't know if that will help.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17308

Does the non-PDO version of the driver cause the same problems?

Comment: Unfortunately (and paradoxically) my framework wants both plug-ins, though the PDO one is what it actually seems to be using. Monday I'll try that updated version and see if there's any way to use the non-PDO version.

Comment: Hm do you know if these are compiled in VC9? I assume they are but I can't seem to get my server to load them